# How to stop Vim highlighting trailing whitespace in python files

Tags: python, vim

Title of the question pretty much describes the problem

In my vimrc file i even typed this:

```
let python_highlight_all = 0
```

But this does not help at all

**UPD:** I got it to work with monkeypatch in python.vim.
I just commented this line:

```
syn match   pythonSpaceError    display excludenl "\s\+$"
```

If someone has a better solution please answer

Comment: `:noh` .......?

Comment: @Chris_Rands does not help, also highliting appears even in insert mode when i typing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim`, the `pythonSpaceError` syntax group is surrounded by an `if exists("python_space_error_highlight")` conditional (in Vim 8.0; using a syntax file from 2016 Oct 29).

So, there's no need to monkey-patch, you can indeed turn this off, by defining **neither** `python_space_error_highlight` **nor** `python_highlight_all` (because the latter definition will automatically define the former, too).

(Even when a config value is `0`, as the script just tests for the *existence* of the variable (which is odd and against the usual convention; you may want to complain about this to the script's author). Therefore, ensure that you don't have of those config variables set, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! There is indeed defined `python_highlight_all` in one of my vimrc's. After deleting it problem is gone.

Answer (score 6):

Here are at least 2 possible reasons for this:

1. `python_highlight_all` is defined
2. `python_space_error_highlight` is defined

Since the problem is gone if you monkeypatch `syntax/python.vim` this highlight should be coming from Vim's default Python syntax file.
In the syntax file, the highlight is controlled by the code below:

```
# vim80/syntax/python.vim
if exists("python_highlight_all")
  ...
  let python_space_error_highlight = 1
endif
```

With this code, `python_space_error_highlight` is enabled if a variable `python_highlight_all` exists regardless of its value.
So probably `python_highlight_all` and/or `python_space_error_highlight` is defined somewhere.

How's the result if you add the code below to your vimrc?

```
if exists('python_highlight_all')
    unlet python_highlight_all
endif
if exists('python_space_error_highlight')
    unlet python_space_error_highlight
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let g:python_highlight_all = 0
```

A string search in the following script gave me that answer

https://github.com/hdima/python-syntax/tree/master/syntax

Comment: Did you try at the begining of your vimrc: before the `syntax on`

Answer (score 0):

I still wanted the other highlights enabled by `python_highlight_all` and found that the option to disable this is actually called `python_highlight_space_errors` not `python_space_error_highlight`. This worked for me:

```
let python_highlight_all = 1
let python_highlight_space_errors = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode), you can set this option in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = 0
```